# MySQL: Reversed GROUP_CONCAT failed. What's wrong?

Tags: mysql

I have a table "source" with columns id and contents.

|id|contents|

|1|Digestion is the process of turning food into fuel for energy|

|2|During the digestive process, food passes down the throat|

|3|The health of your digestive system has a lot to do with lifestyle|

I want to explode this by space.

Here is my script in MySQL workbench:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE explode_table ()
BEGIN
DECLARE idparagraf INTEGER;
DECLARE paragraf TEXT;
DECLARE i INTEGER;
DECLARE h INTEGER;
DECLARE Frase TEXT;
DECLARE input_text TEXT;
DECLARE segmenter VARCHAR(45);
DECLARE exit_loop BOOLEAN default FALSE;
DECLARE my_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT id, contents FROM source;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET exit_loop = TRUE;

SET h=0;
SET i=0;
SET exit_loop=FALSE;
SET segmenter=REPLACE(segmenter, '  ', ' ');
SET input_text=REPLACE(input_text, '  ', ' ');

            CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE WordList
                (
                ID INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
                IdParagraph INTEGER,
                Words TEXT,
                PRIMARY KEY (ID)
                );


OPEN my_cursor;

RowByRow : LOOP

    FETCH  my_cursor INTO idparagraf, paragraf;


    IF exit_loop THEN
        SELECT * FROM WordList;
        CLOSE my_cursor;
        LEAVE RowByRow;
    END IF;

    REPEAT
        SET i=i+1;
            SET Frase = split_string(paragraf,' ', i);
            INSERT INTO WordList
                (ID, IdParagraph, Words)
            VALUES
                (0, idparagraf, Frase);
        UNTIL i = ComplexCount(paragraf,' ')
    END REPEAT;

SELECT * FROM WordList;

END LOOP RowByRow;

END
```

Problem probably lies on DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET exit_loop = TRUE; or  "IF exit_loop THEN" or else?

Your help will be appreciated. Please help

Comment: What results are you expecting? What results did you get? Please see [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on how to post a MVCE.

Comment: I have found a way to explode without cursor and replace above script with it. Forget my question above.